# GitHub action Manual approval process

Tags: devops, github-actions, continuous-delivery

I know that GitHub Action manual triggers is a very discussed issue, manual approval is a bit less discussed but still present in the community.

I have a question for those who use Github actions for CD purposes.

As you know Bitbucket, Gitlab, Azure Devops etc. have a feature *Manual approval* which means that a pipeline can reach a certain step in the process for example: build -> test -> deploy to staging.

The next step is deploy to production yet it needs a manual approval or trigger. So my question is this, were any of you achieve that functionality in GitHub action with the same information (branch name, same test results) without running the whole pipeline again? (It's kind of the reason why I am not migrating us from Bitbucket to GitHub yet)

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recently, the GitHub team has announced [Environments](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-12-15-github-actions-environments-environment-protection-rules-and-environment-secrets-beta/) in beta. With this feature, you can add *Manual approvals* into your CI/CD.

[Environment workflow syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment)

However, there is a restriction for [private](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/setting-repository-visibility) repositories - Only [GitHub Enterprise](https://github.com/pricing) service plan can use *Environments* within private repositories.

Comment: Is there a way to use manual approval without deployments? I'd like to have an authorized user choose whether to sign an RPM on my stable branch or not

Comment: According to [this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#about-environments), "Organizations with GitHub Team and users with GitHub Pro can configure environments for private repositories."

Comment: oh but [this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#required-reviewers) says, "If you are on a GitHub Free, GitHub Pro, or GitHub Team plan, required reviewers are only available for public repositories."

Answer (score 3):

So in GitHub there are two ways to do manual approval for deployments .

1. [Using Environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments)
2. [Using GitHub action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/manual-workflow-approval)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).